# Download of an artifact fails intermittenly in Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a build pipe and as I checked the edited *azure-pipelines.yaml* file (the only change in the commit, it ran automatically with a successful outcome (build 42). Then, I ran it again manually triggering it. To me greatest confusion, it failed!

[image]

There no difference in the source code base: the ID of the commit is **precisely** the same. I don't understand how this can be the case. Consecutive runs turn out to be randomly failing and succeeding. This kind of intermittent behavior suggests that it's not my code as such but an external factor I'm not controlling.

The step that causes the failure is this one.

```
- download: current
  artifact: arty
```

How is it possible that the artifact was there on the initial run (triggered by a push of the YAML file) and not the second one (triggered manually by me)? I have precisely the same step in the job where the artifact is created and it doesn't fail there. For some reason, it seems to be happening on some of the consecutive executions of the build pipe and only in a separate job.

Comment: Can you share the full pipeline and the error log?

Comment: Share your entire pipeline YAML. Are you running jobs in parallel, or have you defined dependencies between them to ensure they run sequentially?

Comment: @DanielMann That's it! I thought that stages were going in parallel but not jobs. Now, that you mentioned that, I realized that the `dependsOn` is applicable even between the jobs. Once that's added, the error stops occurring. I was fooled by the graphical representation of the stages. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jobs can go in parallel, which caused the artifact not always to be available (yet) during the execution of the second job. To enforce sequential execution, `dependsOn` should be used.

```
- job: first_job
  displayName: "This has to complete..."
  ...
- job: second_job
  dependsOn: first_job
  displayName: "...before this will commence."
```